# Auto select specific date when dialog open MUI datepicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

Currently I init my picked date equal to null but when passing that state to datepicker, the dialog does not select any date. But i want the dialog to auto select today , so i just need to press OK to apply (right now i still have to select then press OK to apply)

```
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState<moment.Moment | null>(null);
 <MobileDatePicker value={selectedDate} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question - it is a bit unclear. If you simply want your date picker to auto-set to the current date, just initialize it to `moment()`.

IE:

```
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState<moment.Moment>(moment());
```

This will automatically set your value to the current date.

Comment: Yeah but if i init current date the input will show that day but i don't want that. I want the dialog auto select and the input still show placeholder only